# My speakers (internal) makes a loud buzzing sound when I set the volume to above 90%

Tags: audio, drivers, speakers, windows-10-v1709, windows-insider

Here's the sound it makes, not sure if it'll help: [ONEDRIVE DOWNLOAD LINK](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnVb25RbBCLag55dqpxSh3bExPqc_A), [CLYP LINK](https://clyp.it/djyyu3gf)

It's an internal subwoofer. Here are the details:

> ### DEVICE, DRIVER, AND WI
>
> Device instant path: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0256&SUBSYS_102807E1
>
> Operating system: Windows 10 (x64) Build 17115.rs4_release.180302-1642 (Insider Build)
>
> > Driver version installed: 6.0.1.8142

Please help, I'm worried about my laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are hearing is (almost certainly) an [audio feedback loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_feedback) of some kind. Sound equipment, including sound cards, speakers and microphones, can interact in such a way as to boost the strength of a small input signal to ever increasing volumes of noise. Internal speakers can be particularly prone to this.

Microsoft has some [tips](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2577040/how-to-reduce-the-feedback-loop-between-the-microphone-and-speakers-in) on reducing the possibility of feedback, but the gist is to open your Sound Panel to the *Recording* tab (right-click the Speaker icon in the System Tray and select *Recording*) and:

- Use the *Properties*  button for your microphone to adjust the Microphone Boost under the *Levels* tab (lower it).
- Enable any Noise Suppression or Acoustic Echo Cancelation options for the microphone under the *Enhancements* tab.

Note that, in certain cases, disabling Speaker enhancements (under the *Playback* tab, also under a given device's *Properties* -> *Enhancements*) may help resolve some issues as well. As a small caveat, these options are hardware/software specific so they may or may not be available for you.

Issues can also be caused by using certain audio software. Regarding differences in audio handling, take [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org) and [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) for instance. With Audacity, incoming audio is muted while recording whereas with Voicemeeter, it isn't. This means that I get audio feedback at anything over 20% volume in Voicemeeter if using my internal microphone and speakers simultaneously.

One other thing to try is to simply move any external microphone away from your PC. If it's some kind of internal interaction with the sound card, however, this may not help. Similarly, this is not an option for internal microphones.

Lastly, if all else fails... Just keep the volume below 90%.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention if the problem occurs in both speakers which is an important clue. I will post here what I posted elsewhere. I have an Acer Aspire and one speaker was buzzing. I opened up the case to do a battery disconnect for another purpose and found a tiny bit of steel filing clinging to the cone, magnetically. After closing it up, the speaker still buzzed and so I assumed correctly that there was another filing clinging to the cone. I fixed it completely by passing a powerful permanent magnet over the speaker opening. The openings on this unit face diagonally downward and so can easily pick up ferromagnetic particles through the grills, with the speaker magnets.

Comment: OP notes their question has already been answered, which means that your information, while nice, is incorrect.

Comment: Incorrect? A solution which solved a similar problem is incorrect?